# Vaadin can't save design, throws an error

Tags: java, eclipse, vaadin, vaadin7

[image]

when trying to update a vaadin HTML design, it always showing an error and can not be saved.

"Save Failed
org/eclipse/jdt/internal/corext/codemanipulation/StubUtility"

I have tried for two days to solve this and I don't know how to fix this, it looks like it could be an Eclipse IDE error.

**One Solution I Found**

Using an older version of Eclipse IDE solve the issue of saving, I Downloaded Eclipse IDE oxygen 2 and worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you're having the same problem with https://github.com/vaadin/designer/issues/1987.
As it's fixed, could you try again with the latest Designer version?

Comment: How can I check which designer version I have and how to change it? In eclipse/plugins it shows to jar files com.vaadin.designer_1.4.4 and com.vaadin.designer2_4.2.1

Comment: It appears that I have the newest version, so I should not have this problem

Comment: Designer 1.x for FW7 does not support the newer versions of Eclipse.